# how to move to wayland from xorg in antergos gnome?

Tags: xorg, gnome, wayland, antergos

So I have a recent(2 month) install of antergos with gnome shell.

By default it's using x11 instead of wayland (`echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` return `x11`)

Wayland was already install but not weston, so I installed it using pacman.

Lightdm was also by default but I move to gdm because I think I need to use gdm to use wayland.

On the login screen I have a choice between gnome/gnome with xorg. I always choose gnome but it's still using x11.

I'm using an intel nuc i3 4th generation.

Comment: What graphics adapter do you have? Afaik wayland does not support nvidia yet, and gnome may decide to use X11 backend if you have an nvidia card.

Comment: I use the integrated graphic of my core i3